# How jni deliver a string array?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

How to deliver a string array?

I post the code:

xx.cpp

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Hello_Native(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,jstring string)
{
    const char *str = env->GetStringUTFChars(string, 0);
    return env->NewStringUTF( "Hello from JNI !");
}
static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = {
   {"JniHello",const_cast<char*>("(Ljava/lang/jsting)Ljava/lang/jsting;"),(void*)Hello_Native}
```

xx.java

```
public native static String JniHello(String text);
```

System always prompt it has the problem when declare `JniHello` in `gMethods` and the parameter is not right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. stop using wrong manual names for JNICALL functions. `javah` will generate it for you correctly. If your Java name is `JniHello` in class `MyHello` and your package is `com.hello` , JNICALL function must be `Java_com_hello_MyHello_JniHello`. It can't be `Hello_Native`, you have made it up.
2. then of course this correct function name must be used in the last member of `JNINativeMethod` struct
3. there is no such class as `java/lang/jsting`. There is not even a `java/lang/jstring` if i add the missing `r` for you. You are asked for the JAVA signature, not JNI. So it must be `java/lang/String`.
4. **ADDED (thanks @EJP)**: stop using wrong manual strings for JNI signatures and use the output of `javap -s` instead

Your code has one more problem: when used `GetStringUTFChars`, you must also call `ReleaseStringUTFChars' before returning, otherwise you have a leak. But you will find this yourself sooner or later.

Comment: Good advice. I would add 'stop using wrong manual strings for JNI signatures and use the output of javap -s instead'. That would solve (3). +1

Comment: I prefer the 'stop using' wording that agrees with your own point 1.

Comment: @EJP i wanted to avoid sounding too strong. But for no apparent reason besides vague humanistic feeling, i admit.

Answer (score 1):

const_cast("(Ljava/lang/jsting)Ljava/lang/jsting;")
spell error, should be
const_cast("(Ljava/lang/jsting)Ljava/lang/jstring;")

jsting ==> jstring

Answer (score 1):

```
Copy some android source code to help you(JNI):


static jobject osNetworkSystem_getHostByNameImpl(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz,
        jstring nameStr, jboolean preferIPv6Addresses) {

}

static void osNetworkSystem_setInetAddressImpl(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj,
        jobject sender, jbyteArray address) {

}

static jobject osNetworkSystem_inheritedChannelImpl(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {

}

/*
 * JNI registration.
 */
static JNINativeMethod gMethods[] = {
    /* name, signature, funcPtr */
    { "getHostByNameImpl",                 "(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/net/InetAddress;",                              (void*) osNetworkSystem_getHostByNameImpl                  },
    { "setInetAddressImpl",                "(Ljava/net/InetAddress;[B)V",                                              (void*) osNetworkSystem_setInetAddressImpl                 },
    { "inheritedChannelImpl",              "()Ljava/nio/channels/Channel;",                                            (void*) osNetworkSystem_inheritedChannelImpl               },
};

int register_org_apache_harmony_luni_platform_OSNetworkSystem(JNIEnv* env) {
    return jniRegisterNativeMethods(env,
            "org/apache/harmony/luni/platform/OSNetworkSystem",
            gMethods,
            NELEM(gMethods));
}
```